# cucumber: string to an active record model name

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I'm trying to do a DRY cucumber feature and I'm facing a problem of converting a string into an ActiveRecord model name

```
Given /^the following "(.+)" exist:/ do |mod, table|
  table.hashes.each do |t|
   mod.create!(t)
  end
  assert mod.all.count == table.hashes.size
end
```

that gives

```
undefined method `create!' for "Balloon":String (NoMethodError)
```

More elegant solution might be to use a factory, but I'm wondering whether it is possible to use the above approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into `constantize` which [turns a String into a constant](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize). Try:

```
"Balloon".constantize.create!(t)
```

**BUT:** Using your app code (models in particular) in a Cucumber step is code smell. Your integration tests shouldn't rely on the code under test at all—think of your app as a black box when you implement Cucumber steps. (Also think of a refactoring of your models that require you to go back and change your Cucumber steps—that's your first clue that you're on the wrong track!)

What you could do to improve this is create the models using an API (if your app implements one).

That way, you only rely on those parts of your app that are public-facing.

**On another note:** Your `Given` shouldn't have an assertion, it's more like a `before` hook in RSpec, setting up a condition for a later assertion...